# How to pass object by reference in java?

Tags: java

I've done a lot of research but only found that java cannot pass object by reference. But, then how does `System.arraycopy()` change the value of an array provided.

Comment: You can't pass objects *at all*, actually.

Comment: Have a look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

Comment: What do you think happens when you read all of the data of an array and put it in a newly created array?

Comment: Java only allow passing objects as a reference.  The confusion point is that references are passed by value.

Answer (score 0):

`System.arraycopy()` changes an array's contents, not the object/reference itself. The array you include as input parameter must be declared outside the method.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly what your "pass object" means.
If you means call a function and pass object as parameter. Then in Java, any Object is passed in reference. This means that if you modify that object in the function called, the modification will take effect even function returns.

Comment: Actually, in Java everything *is pass by value*.. even references are passed by value..

Answer (score 0):

`System.arraycopy()` changes contents of an array, not the exact array. However it's possible to write a `Pointer` class.

```
public class Pointer<T>{
    private T value;

    public Pointer(T value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T get(){
        return value;
    }

    public void set(T value){
        this.value = value;
    }
}

Pointer<SomeClass> pointer = new Pointer<>(theObject);

pointer.set(otherObject);
theObject = pointer.get();
```

Or to use "the `System.arraycopy()` trick":

```
SomeClass[] pointer = new SomeClass[]{ theObject };

pointer[0] = otherObject;
theObject = pointer[0];
```